# Let A be a denumerable subset of an uncountable set X. Prove that X/A is uncountable

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'd like to know if my proof is correct:

Assume $A$ is denumerable and and $A\subseteq X$
Assume X is uncountable
(X uncountable means X is not finite and X is not denumerable)

$X=(X\backslash A) \cup (X \cap A)=(X\backslash A)\cup A$
(as $A \subseteq X$)

Therefore $X$ is uncountable $\implies (X\backslash A) \cup (X \cap A)$ uncountable.

Now using the Theorem: If A and B are denumerable sets then $A\cup B$ is denumerable.
The contrapositive of this statement is: If $A\cup B$ is not denumerable then A is not denumerable or B is not denumerable.

Now applying the contrapositive to what we have so far

$(X\backslash A) \cup A)$ uncountable(not denumerable) $\implies(X\backslash A)$ uncountable or $A$ is uncountable.

(by the contrapositive of the theorem)

By assumption A is denumerable and therefore countable hence X\A is uncountable as required.

Comment: Your proof seems fine, but it's "better" to start with assuming $X\setminus A$ is denumerable and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, it might be better to say something like: Suppose $X\setminus A$ is denumerable, then $(X\setminus A)\cup A=X$ is denumerable, contradiction."